# Why votes on question don't change the tag vote count in the User Profile?

Tags: support, tags, user-profiles

When you ask or answer a question the tags of such question appear in your profile, as people vote your answers the tag score on your profile increases/decreases.

Why doesn't it do the same for when you get up/down votes on the question you asked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you're not showing that you're "good" at the tag at hand when asking a good question about it, per se.